# Order of operations for pointers

Tags: c, string

Can you please explain the order of operations for the following function that reverses a string?

```
//http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=589993 source of method
/* reverse a string in place, return str */
static char* reverse(char* str)
{
    char* left  = str;
    char* right = left + strlen(str) - 1;
    char  tmp;
    while (left < right)
    {
        tmp      = *left;
        *left++  = *right;//This part is real confusing...Does ++ happen after the assignment?
        *right-- = tmp;//This one is just as bad
    }
    return str;
}
```

I can follow the first 3 lines in the method pretty easily, but once it hits the while loop I am at a loss for how this works. Specifically the lines marked above.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*left++  = *right
```

In this statement, `*left` is assigned `*right`, and then after all of that `left` (not `*left`) is incremented. The same logic goes for `*right--`

So rewritten, the pseudocode would be this:

```
while(not halfway)
{
    tmp = left value
    left value = right value
    left position += 1
    right value = tmp
    right position -= 1        
}
```

Comment: So, then are we saying the following?
1.  Dereference both char locations and assign right's character to left
2.  Take the memory address of left and increment it by 1

Comment: @Xxxx: Yes. I'd recommend you read about pre and post increments. They are getting even more complicated in C++.

Comment: @Xxxx, @B Mitch, no, that's not correct. The increment does not happen after the assignment. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The post decrement operators happen after the dereference, and so effectively (in your code) after the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the code, it's easier if you add parentheses to it:

```
*left++  = *right;
```

Is the same as:

```
*(left++) = *right;
```

On other words, the ++ is applied to the pointer, not to what the pointer points to.

As this is the post increment operator, the side effect takes place after the value of `left` has been used. In other words, this is the same as:

```
*left = *right;
left++;
```

Comment: No, the side effect does not take place afterwards. The order is undefined. A great example of the undefinedness is what would happen if, prior to this statement, you wrote `left = (char *)&left;` All you can say with certainty is that the expression `left++` evaluates to the *old value of* `left`, but you can make no reasonable statement about whether the value of `left` has changed or not between then and the next sequence point.

Comment: Auhm, this was a question from a beginner that did not understand the basics of the `++` operator. In that light I still stand by my answer. In addition, in the original program in the question, the variable `left` is not aliased in any way (i.e. it's address has not been taken), so the effect of the sequence I presented is the same as the statement in the original program. There really is no need to split hair in which order the write to `*left` and the write to `left` would take place, under totally different circumstances.

Comment: The reason I'm splitting hairs is that it's a common beginner mistake to think the increment happens "after the statement", or to think it happens "immediately" and causes "a copy" of the variable to be created with the old value. Both of these views are wrong, at least in C (the latter is sometimes true in C++ I hear), and lead to misguided attempts at optimization or invocation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You got it.

```
*left++  = *right;
```

1. dereference `*right`
2. store (1) at `*left`
3. increment `left`

```
*right-- = tmp;
```

1. store `tmp` at `*right`
2. decrement `right`

Postfix increment/decrement (`++`/`--`) operators have the higher precedence than dereferencing (`*`).  So `*left++` is parsed as `*(left++)`.  Being a post increment operation, the incrementation occurs after this sequence (i.e., after the assignment takes place).

Comment: Postfix `++` and `--` have *higher* precedence than unary `*`; the prefix versions have the same precedence.

Comment: @John: Oops, you're right.  Where's my head gone?  Working overtime can do that to you.  :|

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
*left++ = *right;
```

has two side effects: `left` is incremented to point to the next element of the array it's pointing to, and the value read from the address `right` is stored at the location `left` pointed to *prior to the increment*. However there is no ordering defined between whether the storage to the pointer variable `left` happens before or after the storage to the character it pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix operators (which include `++` and `--`) have higher precedence than unary operators (such as `*`).  Thus, the expression `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`, so the `*` is applied to the *result* of `p++`.

So,

```
*left++ = *right;
```

is equivalent to

```
*left = *right;
left++;
```

Comment: Except the latter would be well-defined if `left` happened to initially point to itself, and the former would not. They're not "equivalent" in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does ++ happen after the assignment?*

No. The increment of `p` probably happens before the assignment occurs, but that's not really important here.

The important part is that the assignment only sees the value `p` had before `p` was incremented. `p++` no more returns `p` than `!x` returns `x`.

`p++` returns the original value of `p` along the same lines as

```
TYPE* post_inc(TYPE* p) {
   TYPE* tmp = p;
   ++p;
   return tmp;
}
```

All together, it looks something like:

```
    tmp = *left;

    anon0 = left;
    ++left;
    *anon0 = *right;

    anon1 = right;
    --right;
    *anon1 = tmp;
```

(Actual order may vary some.)

Comment: It takes place neither before nor after; the order is undefined.

Comment: @R.. Indeed. A word got deleted by accident.